# flask - nested resources

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I'm writing a restful server with flask in python and I'm looking for a way to create nested resources in separated files. For example, if I have resource named Foo and sub-resource named Bar, instead of writing something like this:

demo_app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
name_space = api.namespace('foo')


@name_space.route('/')
class Foo(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return 'foo'


@name_space.route('/bar')
class Bar(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return 'bar'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to write Foo and Bar in different files:

demo_app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
name_space = api.namespace('foo') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

foo.py:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from Receiver.demo_app import name_space
@name_space.route('/')
class Foo(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return 'foo'
```

bar.py:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from Receiver.demo_app import name_space 
@name_space.route('/bar')
class Bar(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return 'bar'
```

But when I write it that way I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

How can I connect between those classes? 
Is there another way to write nested resources?

Answer (score 0):

`foo.py` and `bar.py` won't take effect unless they're imported into the rest of your code.  You need to add to `demo_app.py`:

```
from . import foo, bar
```

This use of circular imports is the same as the recommended approach for splitting up references to `app`; cf. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/.